# How to fix an error "Expected declaration" in Swift?

Tags: swift, void

I have a little bit misunderstanding how to use -(void) in swift correctly. Whenever I have tried to write a code using -(Void) but I am getting an error "`Expected declaration`" or sometimes "`Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIFont' and '(Void).Type'`".

Why is this happening? What is the right way to use this functionality correctly in swift?

{

```
- (Void)keyboardWillShow { //>> showing me the error "Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIFont' and '(Void).Type'"
        // Animate the current view out of the way
        if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
        else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
        }
    }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Please read through [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) for the Swift programming language.

Comment: Update your question with actual code that is causing your issue.

Comment: That's Objective-C code, not Swift code. Please read the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to declare a function with no return value.  In Swift this is done as:

```
func thisFunction() {
  ..
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can return nil value like below code:

```
func myFunc(myVar: String) -> ()? {
    print(myVar)
    return nil
    }
var c = myFunc("Hello") 
print(c) // nil
```

but Swift Function always return default value nil if not declared. like below code:

```
func myFunc(myVar: String) {
        print(myVar)
        return
        }
    var c = myFunc("Hello") 
    print(c) // ()
```

Comment: *Swift Function always return default value nil if not declared* is wrong. In the second example you'll get a compiler error (actually two in Swift 3+).

Comment: *"Swift Function always return default value nil if not declared"* - No, this is not true.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this version of the myFunc(myVar:) function does still return a value, even though no return value is defined. Functions without a defined return type return a special value of type Void. This is simply an empty tuple, which is written as ().

Comment: @AnandVerma Then why does your answer state *"Swift Function always return default value nil if not declared"*? And why have `return` as the last line of the method?